# Amount of apps you create

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a limit to the amount of apps you can create on the Google Play Android platform. I apologize in advance if this question was answered, I searched the forum multiple times but could not find an answer.

I am looking forward to a long term relationship building apps, but wanted to see if there was a cap, or limit, to how many apps you can submit to Google Play.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to belong in Google play support . Really.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no limit to the amount of apps you may publish.

However, each app must have a unique package name, and it is conceivable that you will run out of unique package names eventually (although it'll take you a really long time).

There is a 65535 character limit on the length due to Java's Virtual Machine constraints. However, you're more likely to run into filesystem problems if your package name is too big to fit into the path. For example, the Windows NT Kernel limits file names to  32767 characters, which is a limit you'll hit before the Java one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the lightning fast reply Raghav!!!! I appreciate your answer.